# Selecting on multiple criteria

Tags: python, pandas, plot

I made this dataframe, which contains dates as datetime64 values.
What I want to do is a bit of a stupid example, but it illustrates my point of selecting on multiple criteria.

I want to:
For the year 2018: plot a bar chart grouped per month, of the different values. So I want to create one graph for 2018, showing on the x-axis 12 times 3 bars.

I hope someone has some idea how this works.

Thank you in advance

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random

date_expected = np.arange('2006-01', '2008-06', dtype= 'datetime64[D]')
cat = ['True','False', 'Maybe']

value = [random.choice(cat) for i in range(len(date_expected))]

data = {'Date_expected': date_expected,  'Value': value }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, create a column with the month. Then, group by month and value and get the count.
You need to unstack to get the one column of count per value so that you can plot the bar chart.

```
df['month'] = df['Date_expected'].apply(lambda x: x.month)
df.groupby(['month', 'Value']).count().unstack().plot(kind='bar')
```

[image: result]

Comment: Thanx, but I think this does not really solve my issue, since I’m still not selecting only the 2018 values.

Comment: Hi, 2018 is not in the dataframe but you can select 2018 data prior to the `groupby` method by creating a boolean index with `idx = df['Date_expected'].apply(lambda x: x.year) == 2018`. Then, go with `df[idx].groupby(['month', 'Value']).count()` ...